# Is there a way to get the market cap or market cap rank of a coin using the Binance API?

Tags: c#, .net, bitcoin, binance

I checked all the functions I can think of but I don't see anything for this in the Binance C# API:
https://github.com/JKorf/Binance.Net

All I want is to list the coins I am showing in a list view in the order of their market cap rank, if possible.

Comment: Sorry, but if you're able to get all coins, what's the problem to group them by market? Note: i know nothing about Binance API. Seems, it should be done by client side.

Comment: What do you mean by market? Like USDT, etc? I just want to sort them by market cap rank.

Comment: Try https://coinmarketcap.com/api/

Comment: @Lessmore: I know this one but I need a free api.

Comment: coinmarketcap have free plan

Answer (score 14):

There is no "legal" way to get this data.
This is how I do that:

```
https://www.binance.com/exchange-api/v2/public/asset-service/product/get-products
```

GET this endpoint. It used for Binance SPA and does not mention in their documentation.
`data` is an array that contains all trading Binance pairs. For example:

```
"s":"BTCUSDT",
"st":"TRADING",
"b":"BTC",
"q":"USDT",
"ba":"฿",
"a":"",
"I":"0.00000100",
"ts":"0.01",
"an":"Bitcoin",
"qn":"TetherUS",
"o":"46915.84",
"h":"47499.43",
"l":"44961.09",
"c":"46791.85",
"v":"91500.82",
"qv":"4248420233.17226301",
"y":0,
"as":91500.81462400,
"pm":"FIAT",
"pn":"FIAT",
"cs":18620881,
"tags":["pow","mining-zone"],
"pom":false,
"pomt":null,
"etf":false
```

You need to take the field `cs` and multiply it to the current asset price. In this case, it will be field `c`

`18620881 * 46791.85 = 871,305M`

So it's current BTC market cap

Comment: Thx but how do you separate these into different coins? I was looking for new lines or commands but not sure how to turn this string into proper array elements so i can do a search on the coin I am interested in.

Comment: Actually I just noticed this method doesn't have a valid cs for all coins. Like DOTUSDT cs returns null.

Comment: For separate I take ```b``` value - it's my looking coin. And ```q``` must be USDT. Then I scan the whole array to get this value. I can cache ```cs``` cause it does not change a lot.

Comment: Yes I did that but if you check DOTUSDT, it's null for cs

Comment: {"s":"DOTUSDT","st":"TRADING","b":"DOT","q":"USDT","ba":"","qa":"","i":"0.01000000","ts":"0.0001","an":"Polkadot","qn":"TetherUS","o":"22.9500","h":"24.7900","l":"22.2269","c":"24.7604","v":"14132164.3200","qv":"329851071.227743","y":0,"as":14132164.32000000,"pm":"FIAT","pn":"FIAT","cs":null,"tags":["pos","mining-zone"],"pom":false,"pomt":null,"etf":false},

Comment: You are right. The method does not have cs value for some coins. And Binance does not show the market cap for it on its front page. It's very common for defi coins.

Comment: So Binance knows nothing about its market cap and you can't find it on Binance.

Comment: Oh i see, ok then I will have to find another method.

Comment: Did you end up finding the other method? an update on your quest is appreciated. @JoanVenge

Comment: @AlexDeft No I didnt use anything. So I exclude this data for now.

Comment: I came to realize it is fairly stable. You don't need an update on rank every minute! once you grab them from CMC they will be good enough for at least week.

Answer (score 6):

If you just need a free API and not necessarily Binance you could use CoinGecko's API. Check the docs here:

https://www.coingecko.com/api/documentations/v3

The endpoint you need is /coins/markets.

Try this out https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc

You may want to know the supported vs_currencies to set the vs_currency parameter.
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/supported_vs_currencies

Comment: This is really valuable information, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Please note that the Binance endpoint changed on the 19/06/2023 from the on in [@Mike Malyi 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66134198/13164928) to

```
https://www.binance.com/bapi/asset/v2/public/asset-service/product/get-products?includeEtf=true
```

The only thing changed is the addition of a `ks` boolean parameter. So the complete body is now something like the following:

```json
{
  "code": "000000",
  "message": null,
  "messageDetail": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "s": "BNBBTC",
      "st": "TRADING",
      "b": "BNB",
      "q": "BTC",
      "ba": "",
      "qa": "฿",
      "i": "0.00100000",
      "ts": "0.000001",
      "an": "BNB",
      "qn": "Bitcoin",
      "o": "0.009263",
      "h": "0.009271",
      "l": "0.009034",
      "c": "0.009042",
      "v": "56635.970000",
      "qv": "520.08527786",
      "y": 0,
      "as": 56635.97,
      "pm": "BTC",
      "pn": "BTC",
      "cs": 155853296,
      "tags": [
        "Layer1_Layer2",
        "BSC",
        "pos",
        "bnbchain"
      ],
      "pom": false,
      "pomt": null,
      "lc": false,
      "g": true,
      "sd": false,
      "r": false,
      "hd": false,
      "rb": false,
      "ks": false,
      "etf": false
    },
    {
    ...
    }
  ],
  "success": true
}
```

For the `market cap` calculation please refer to the previous correct [@Mike Malyi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66134198/13164928).

Comment: ZappaBoy you're my hero

Comment: Glad to help the community 

Comment: some coins are missing in this endpoint